# Node Js in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, node.js, web, visual-studio-code

How do i run node.js in visual studio code or on my Website?

Let's assume i got some basic code in VSC:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
```

How do i connect that with my html code?

At the moment im trying it like that:

```
<script>
    const Web3 = require('web3');
</script>
```

I also tryed to import the code as a js:

```
<script src="zahlung.js"></script>
```

But i always get errors with 'require'.

Comment: If you are importing the project, then you have to run "npm install" to install the dependencies mentioned in your package.json file of your project. Also if you are getting error related to web3 dependency, then please install this dependency first on your system by running the command "npm i web3"

Comment: I already installed web3 and node.js on my System, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to understand the difference between server code (executed on server side) and client code (executed on client side - e.g. in the browser).

Furthermore it might be helpful for you to understand that:

1. NodeJS is a runtime environment which allows you to execute JavaScript Code on server side
2. The interaction between client and server can e.g. be done via https requests

Comment: Oh okay, i'll have a look on that topic then... Thank you!